# Why Is Date Format Wrong after publishing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a C# MVC5 application where I want to display a date in the format `yyyy/MM/dd`. I use the following code :

```
public TestController : Controller {
   public string Date()
   {
      return String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", DateTime.Now);
   }
}
```

When I access the url /Test/Date, I get the following result :

- On my machine : `2015/01/23`
- When I publish it on IIS : `2015-01-23`

It is exactly the same code, but not the same result. Any idea what might be the cause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of the current culture on server, which uses `-` as [date separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `/`. Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in `ToString` overload like:

```
public string Date()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: You could also look into explicitly setting the culture of your application.